# How to remove double quotes from the nested list in python

Tags: python, list

I have small nested list like this `["['95', '66', '137', '70', '20']"]`. I want to remove `"` for my nested list. How to do this?

Comment: ```.replace()```. Since it is a string? or you want to convert the string to a list?

Comment: It sounds like you have a list of one element which is a string. So not a nested list at all.

Comment: replace is not working; since it is alist it has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: I mean ```your_list[0].replace("\"",'')```

Comment: @Sujay: Lol, you won't find any `'"'` in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex with `re.findall`

```
import re

lst = ["['95', '66', '137', '70', '20']"]
lst = re.findall(r'\d+', lst[0])
print(lst) # ['95', '66', '137', '70', '20']
```

Comment: what is re? you have not defined that

Comment: @acousticpython It's a library, you need to import it. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
import ast 
mystr = ["['95', '66', '137', '70', '20']"]
print(ast.literal_eval(mystr[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast

ini_list = ["['95', '66', '137', '70', '20']"]
result = []

print(f"ini_list is: {ini_list}")

# Converting string to list
for i in ini_list:
    result.append(ast.literal_eval(i))

# printing final result and its type
print(result)
```

Ouput

```
ini_list is: ["['95', '66', '137', '70', '20']"]
['95', '66', '137', '70', '20']
```

Answer (score 0):

Same  as Sam but without the import. ( not sure why the import is needed)

```
mystr = ["['95', '66', '137', '70', '20']"]
print(eval(mystr[0]))
```

Comment: You shouldn't encourage the use of `eval()` now that `ast` is available.

Comment: Oh , just  read about the difference. ... I was not aware of it . : )  ast.literal_eval raises an exception if the input isn't a valid Python datatype .... so better use  ast... Thank @quamrana

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def return_without_quotes(x):
    y = []
    x = x[0]
    x  =  x.strip(']['' ').split(', ')
    for i in range(len(x)):
        match = re.search('[0-9]+',x[i])
        if match != None:
            y.append(match.group())
    x = [y]

    return x
        

x = ["['95', '66', '137', '70', '20']"]

print(return_without_quotes(x))
```